# Waveform for 24/32 bit WAV files

Tags: java, wav, 32-bit, waveform, 24-bit

I'm working with WAV files in Java and I created a waveform, but it's only able to show the waveform from a 16 bit file. I create one loop for the samples frames and other for the channels, allowing creating waveforms for each channel.

```
for (int indexNumSampleFrames = 0; indexNumSampleFrames < intNumSampleFrames; indexNumSampleFrames++) {
    for (int indexNumChannels = 0; indexNumChannels < intNumChannels; indexNumChannels++) {

        long lgnAmplitude = 0;

        lgnAmplitude = (short) ( arrayData[intPointer] & 0xff) | 
                   (short) ((arrayData[intPointer + 1] & 0xff) << 8);

        intPointer += intBytesPerSample;

        matrixAmplitudes[indexNumChannels][intSampleIndex] = lgnAmplitude;
    }

    intSampleIndex++;
}
```

I'm struggling to create the waveform for 24 and 32 bits... I tried to find any solution but I couldn't, and I also tried the following code without success.

```
lgnAmplitude = (long) ( arrayData[intPointer] & 0xff) | 
                               (long) ((arrayData[intPointer + 1] & 0xff) << 8) |
                               (long) ((arrayData[intPointer + 2] & 0xff) << 16);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change `intBytesPerSample` accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I did.
intBytesPerSample = intBitsPerSample / 8